# send form values with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to send specfic form data to a php update script to modify the stored values in our database, how do i pass the hidden value and the checked value.

```
<?php do { ?>
 <form>
<p> <?php echo $row_tasks['dept']; ?> / <?php echo $row_tasks['descrip']; ?> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="status" value="<?php echo $row_tasks['id']; ?   >">
  <input type="hidden"   id="tid" value="<?php echo $row_tasks['id']; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Submit" />
 </p>
 </form>
 <?php } while ($row_tasks = mysql_fetch_assoc($tasks)); ?>
 <script>
  function showValues() {
  var str = $("form").serialize();
  $("#results").text(str);
 }
$(":checkbox, :radio").change(showValues);
$("select").change(showValues);
showValues();
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
return false;
 });
 </script>
 <p><tt id="results"></tt></p
```

Answer (score 2):

give the hidden input a name..

Comment: ok redid the script and now the correct values show when on the alert step but the post data is equal to the last form generated, how do i have to only post the same values the serialize function has

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

$('form').submit(function() { $.post("/scripts/savetask.php", $("this").serialize());  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
}); </script>

Comment: <?php do { ?>
    <form method="post">
      <p> <?php echo $row_tasks['dept']; ?> / <?php echo $row_tasks['descrip']; ?> 
        <input name="sid" type="hidden" id="sid" value="1">
        <input name="tid" type="hidden"   id="tid" value="<?php echo $row_tasks['id']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Submit" />
      </p>
    </form>
    <?php } while ($row_tasks = mysql_fetch_assoc($tasks)); ?>
<div class="success" style="display: none;">Task has been added.</div>